# google-speech-to-text API transcription response gets numbers instead words

Tags: speech-to-text, google-speech-api, google-cloud-speech, transcription, speech-recognition-api

I use the code: which works fine with a sound file in the English language but why in a sound file in another language when I update the code to recognize another language accordingly I get the results in the response in numbers and not words, can you please help, I am a new student in this subject?, thanks

```
from google.cloud import speech

speech_client = speech.SpeechClient.from_service_account_file('key.json')
media_file_name = 't2.wav'
with open (media_file_name,'rb') as f:
byte_data_wav = f.read()
audio_wav =speech.RecognitionAudio(content=byte_data_wav)
config_wav = speech.RecognitionConfig(
sample_rate_hertz=44100,
enable_automatic_punctuation = True,
language_code ='iw-IL',
audio_channel_count=1
)
response_wav = speech_client.recognize(
config = config_wav,
audio  =  audio_wav
)
print(response_wav)




---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

results {
alternatives {
transcript: "\\327\\244\\327\\250\\327\\251\\327\\252 \\327\\221\\327\\250\\327\\220\\327\\251\\327\\231\\327\\252 \\327\\221\\327\\250\\327\\220\\327\\251\\327\\231\\327\\252 \\327\\221\\327\\250\\327\\220 \\327\\220\\327\\234\\327\\225\\327\\224\\327\\231\\327\\235 \\327\\220\\327\\252 \\327\\224\\327\\251\\327\\236\\327\\231\\327\\231\\327\\235 \\327\\225\\327\\220\\327\\252 \\327\\224\\327\\220\\327\\250\\327\\245 \\327\\225\\327\\224\\327\\220\\327\\250\\327\\245 \\327\\224\\327\\231\\327\\231\\327\\252\\327\\224 \\327\\252\\327\\225\\327\\224\\327\\225 \\327\\225\\327\\221\\327\\225\\327\\224\\327\\225 \\327\\225\\327\\227\\327\\225\\327\\251\\327\\232 \\327\\242\\327\\234 \\327\\244\\327\\240\\327\\231 \\327\\252\\327\\224\\327\\225\\327\\235"
confidence: 0.9430100917816162
}
result_end_time {
seconds: 24
nanos: 540000000
}
language_code: "he-il"
}
total_billed_time {
seconds: 25
}
request_id: 2840050288344987275
```